# Authenticate on other platform after creating account using Apple Signin on iOS device

Tags: android, ios, apple-sign-in

Let's say a user create an account on my app using Apple Signin on his iOS device and choose to not share his email causing his account to be identified by an email address like *dpdcnf87nu@privaterelay.appleid.com* and not his "real" email address like for example *j.appleseed@icloud.com*.

Time later the user switch to an Android device and wants to signin to my app using his account, that is the one he previously created using Apple Signin on his iOS device.

How would you simplify the user journey allowing him to login into his account on his new Android device avoiding that he creates a new account using another method like Facebook Login (that inevitably leads to the creation of a new account - different email=different account)?

Answer (score 0):

You should identify user by id, which OAuth returns not by email address. You will get the same id on another device even if they choose hide email. You should store this field in order to identify users.
In order to get userId you should request token rest API and get userId:
`https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token`. If you use Apple [js api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple) you will receive id_token as well.

```
 var id_token = responseJSON.GetValue("id_token").ToString();
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
 var jwt = handler.ReadJwtToken(id_token);
 var userId = jwt.Claims.FirstOrDefault((c) => c.Type == "sub").Value;
```